# Rails 3.2 Model scope date less_than_a_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to create a scope which can find the dataset for example, less_than_a_year, less_than_six_month, in my model through my deadline attribute.

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :title, :detail, :deadline, :achieve

  #need help solving this
  scope :less_than_a_year, where()
end
```

So it would perform, goal.less_than_a_year and provide a list of data less then a year.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [rails 3.2 guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-times)

```
scope :less_than_a_year, lambda { where("deadline < ?", 1.year.from_now ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is database specific, but it should work for most.

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :less_than_a_year, lambda{ where("deadline < ?", 1.year.from_now) }
end
```

This assumes that deadline is a `Date` or `DateTime`.

**Edit**: added lambda (i swear i did this before I saw the other answers, but not before the downvote)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base

 #need help solving this
 scope :less_than_a_year, labmda { where("deadline < ", 1.year.ago)}

end
```

Comment: you forgot the ? and misspelled lambda